# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require("buffer").constants.MAX_LENGTH')

Tags: javascript, azure-storage

Всем привет

Пытаюсь импортную BlobServiceClient из azure/storage-blob

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
```

Падает с ошибкой

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require("buffer").constants.MAX_LENGTH')
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Какая версия Node.js у вас?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty 14.15.4

Comment: Странно.  `require("buffer").constants` , [судя по докам](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_constants), добавили в 8-й.

Comment: Стоит, наверное, добавить в вопрос весь стек ошибки, чтобы была понятна цепочка вызовов, вдруг кому станет от того понятнее причина.